# Resolving field name conflicts in tables involved in Django multi-table inheritance

Tags: django, django-models

I'm looking for a good way to resolve the field name conflict that occurs in the following models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class OauthProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    oauth_token = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    oauth_secret = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class TwitterProfileInfo(OauthProfile):

    user_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
```

The OauthProfile model gives rise to a column named user_id in the appname_oauthprofile table, and the TwitterProfileInfo model, which inherits from OauthProfile gives rise to a column by the same name in the appname_twitterprofileinfo table.  The profile is purposely being created before the root User object, so I've defined the OauthProfile user property to allow NULL, with a default of None.

When saving an object of type TwitterProfileInfo without assigning a value to its user property or explicitly assigning it to None, I was expecting appname_oauthprofile.user_id to be left NULL in the database.  Instead, looking at the PostgreSQL log, I can see it's being assigned the value I had assigned to the object's user_id property.  This causes a referential integrity error because there's no row in the auth_user table having that value.

```
myProfile = TwitterProfileInfo()
myProfile.user = None
myProfile.user_id = 12345 # Django tries to assign this to appname_oauthprofile.user_id
myProfile.screen_name = 'sometwitteruser'
myProfile.oauth_token = '1234567890abcdefg'
myProfile.oauth_secret = 'sometauthtokensecret'
myProfile.save() # results in error
```

I could just rename one of the conflicting fields, changing the TwitterProfileInfo field name to something like twitter_user_id, for example.  But I'm wondering if there is a way to resolve this conflict without doing that.  If I didn't have control of the database and was constrained to use these column names, how would I define these models to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django's multi-table inheritance is such an antipattern. It has all sorts of horrible consequences, like the one you've noticed.

The answer to your question is, don't use inheritance. Use an explicit OneToOneField between `TwitterProfileInfo` and `OauthProfile`. The database structure is exactly the same, and you'll have complete control of how you refer to your fields. The only difference is that you'll need to instantiate and save the `OauthProfile` object separately, and explicitly set the relationship:

```
my_oauth = OauthProfile(oauth_token='1234567890abcdefg', oauth_secret='sometauthtokensecret')
my_oauth.save()
my_twitter = TwitterProfileInfo(oauth_profile=my_oauth, user_id=12345)
my_twitter.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why I didn't think of the db_column option originally.  This works fine, at least as far as this example goes:

```
class TwitterProfileInfo(OauthProfile):

    twitter_user_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='user_id', unique=True)
    screen_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True)
```

Then elsewhere...

```
myProfile = TwitterProfileInfo()
myProfile.user = None
myProfile.twitter_user_id = 12345 # use the "custom" attribute name instead
myProfile.screen_name = 'sometwitteruser'
myProfile.oauth_token = '1234567890abcdefg'
myProfile.oauth_secret = 'sometauthtokensecret'
myProfile.save() # no error
```

Still, I'm curious about negative consequences associated with Django's multi-table inheritance.  If they're significant, then I'll be inclined to accept [Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) answer.